# Single query to find document with largest value for some field

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got a collection of documents that have unique numeric run ids, and I want to find the document with the highest run id.

I can do that two queries.

Firstly, I can find the highest run id:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggregations": {
      "latest_run_id": {
        "aggregations": {
          "latest_run_id": {
            "max": {"field": "run_id"}
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Secondly, I can find the document with that run id:

```
{
    "filter": {
        {"term": {"run_id": latest_run_id}}
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can do this with a single query?

Comment: For what purpose do you want to retrieve the largest id? Maybe to set the next available id for a new document?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can accomplish this by combining `"sort"` and `"size"`:

```
{
 "filter" : {
   "match_all" : { }
 },
 "sort": [
   {
     "run_id": {
       "order": "desc"
     }
   }
 ],
 "size": 1
}
```

This will return the record with the highest value for `run_id`

Comment: How can we achieve this using java API?

Comment: Thanks - This is exactly what I was looking for as well.

Comment: It seems that this not work on char fields on ES 7.10

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to retrieve entire document holding max value using **top hits** aggregation

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs":{
        "doc_with_max_run_id": {
            "top_hits": {
                "sort": [
                    {
                        "latest_run_id": {
                            "order": "desc"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "size": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also by modifying 'size' aggregation parameter it is possible to retrieve n-top documents.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for ids above 99999. When I'm performing this query, 99999 is being returned as the top id, but there are definitely ids in the 100k+ range. This is on Elasticsearch 6.2, so this query might just not be compatible with newer versions.

Comment: Strange. Seems like you have id based on string values not integer or longs. 9 is always on the top for string types when sorted DESC - that's why i think it is String.

Comment: is this faster or slower than the "sort+size" solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this result in java with the following code

```
SearchResponse max_r = maxCTSRB.setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
        .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.max("latest_run_id").field("run_id"))
        .addSort(new FieldSortBuilder("run_id").order(SortOrder.DESC))
        setSize(1).execute().get();
```

The aggregation is there only for validation. you can completely omit it

Answer (score 0):

Just translating in C# what Adam Drewery said above.

```
var response = await elasticSearchContext.ElasticClient.SearchAsync<MyClass>(s =>
                s.Query(q => q.MatchAll()).Sort(d => d.Descending(p => p.run_id)).Size(1));
```